# Breakfast cereal brachot

Tags: blessing, food, internet

Is there a reliable on-line source for finding the brerachot for commercially prepared breakfast cereals?

Answer (score 4):

A lot of the popular American ones appear on [this list](http://www.star-k.org/cons-appr-cereal.htm) from the Star-K, a reliably-regarded source.

[Here](http://www.ka.org.au/index2.php?option=com%5Fcontent&task=view&id=67&pop=1&page=0&Itemid=87) is a less extensive list if you're looking for Australian cereals.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a site I stumbled on by mistake: [Brochos.](http://www.brochos.com)

Comment: Best answer in my opinion.

Comment: It doesn't look comprehensive. Two of the three cereals I tried, Fruit Loops and Honeycombs the latter because of Yahu's answer, were not listed. The third, Cheerios, had listings for a bunch of different varieties.

Comment: That's because different Cheerios are made different ways hence different Brachos I think he redid the site recently and lost a lot of his data. He happens to be on pf the only sites that has a Bracha for wraps and he has it from Reb Eliyashiv.

Comment: and he has a free sefirah,rosh chodesh,erev Tavshilim Reminder text service at http://www.tizkor.com/

Comment: Issac he has them both you might want to try alternate spellings.

Comment: I stand corrected. I guess the search tool could use a little work, but the list is more comprehensive than I thought.

Comment: I say it is the best answer because it directly addresses the question that was asked and although I may have trouble with Rav Bodner's psakim on Licorice Twists and Honey combs (and rice Cakes) does not make him unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

That list from the Star-K is so reliable that the author of the Hebrew sefer וזאת הברכה chose to include that English list as an insert. Just a word of caution, though: As indicated on the bottom of that page, things do change - ingredients change, formulas change, pareve/dairy status change. Make sure to check back periodically.

Also, notice Corn Pops are האדמה in the US only. The formula in Canada is different and they are שהכל.

Answer (score 2):

Another problem with the Star-K list is that it lists Honeycombs as shehakol because the first ingredient is corn meal. The problem is that another main ingredient is oat flour which might not be secondary (since significant mezonos is never tafel) and would therefore make its bracha mezonos. Ask your Rav about any cereal you have a doubt on. No list can take his place.

Shalom, licorice twists need to have flour in order to be licorice twists. Without the flour you would merely have "corn syrup-flavoring-food coloring goop". The flour is what makes it into the candy-noodle that we enjoy. To say that the flour in licorice twists is insignificant is very questionable. When I was younger all the brachos guides said to make a mezonos on them and then relatively recently this shehakol idea, based on what you are saying surfaced and became "popular".

There is a Tosafos in Brachos which says that if the mezonos is just a binder or thickener then it is *Tafel* (secondary). The point of this is that a binder or thickener is insignificant. Some examples of this are: bread crumbs in meatballs, bread in meatloaf, flour in soup. All of these examples are already a food that people would eat without the enhancement. To stretch this principle of insignificant use of mezonos being tafel to something such as licorice twists (that would just be goop if not for the flour) is a strain on my poor brain.

In Honey Combs, the oats are not just to make the cereal sound more wholesome; they are the third or fourth ingredient! The only possibility as to why the star-k says to make a shehakol is they hold the oat flour is merely being used as a binder, but my impression is that oat flour is a very poor binder! We need to ask the cereal company for what function is it included in the ingredients.

Comment: The issue is the "significance" of the mezonos.  I heard one rabbi suggest that the oats are there just to make the cereal sound more wholesome.  Similar question with "licorice twists"; the flour might just be a binder or a cheap bulking agent.

Comment: Shalom, I responded to your comment by editing the text of my answer.